# Visual Studio 2013 crashes whenever I open a design panel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, crash

My Visual Studio 2013 was performing normally till yesterday, in a winform application I tried to open a design panel and it suddenly crashed without an error message or exception.
There is no solution to my problem at social MSDN I checked.
Please If you know why this is happening help me.

**EDIT:**
VS 2013 first stops working. Cause of the crash is SEHexception, I dont know if a .dll file is missing or not, does anyone ever encountered with this problem or anyone know how to fix it ?

Comment: This is completely impossible to answer.. Are you sure there arent any errors?

Comment: There is no event log or something? Or run with [`/log`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx) option to check it?

Comment: Does VS work as expected on other projects?

Comment: there is no error message I'm sure, whenever an exception occurs or  I open a design panel it suddenly crashes and reopen itself.

Comment: Can you explain the details of the crash? Did the window just suddenly closed or "Visual Studio has stopped working" or something like that?

Comment: @Wolf I tried to run a simple console application and it run normally. Probably it is about winform applications.

Comment: @Sweeper  first stops working without any error message and restarts with start page

Comment: @BarisY Oh I had this problem before! And after restarting visual studio for a few times it is fixed.

Comment: Did you already try to work on another winform application?

Comment: @Wolf I already tried to work another winform app I told you whenever I open a design panel or an exception occurs vs crashes

Comment: @BarisY What about reinstalling?